# Pandas - How to store result of duplicated method as boolean in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to add a column to it and to assign values to the new column based on what `duplicated()` method on a specific column value duplication returns. This is the code I have now:

```
df['duplicated'] = df.duplicated(subset='specific_column', keep=False)
```

The result of the above line is displayed as `True` or `False`. However, the actual type of my new 'duplicated' column value are neither boolean nor string, rather they're of type 'method'. So, my question is how can I store the results as boolean True or False so that I can later use those in further checks. I assume there should be a way to store them as str too.

******** Update & Answer ********
I'm adding a reproducible dataframe to better explain my question and how I realized the naming issue that I had in my code:

```
df = {'specific_column': ['A', 'A', 'B'], 'some_value': [1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

specific_column     some_value
0   A           1
1   A           2
2   B           3

df ['duplicated'] = df.duplicated(subset='specific_column', keep=False)

    specific_column     some_value  duplicated
      0     A       1             True
      1     A       2             True
      2     B       3             False
```

Now, the type of df.duplicated is of course 'method'! Rather, I had to use `df['duplicated']` or I could choose a different name for my new column not to be confused with the `DataFrame.duplicated()` method.

Comment: when i do it against my test DF, i got `df.duplicated` of type `bool`, so you would have to provide reproducible sample input data frame

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comment, I actually realized what the issue was. I've edited my question to include the answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I realized it was a naming issue when I was checking the type of `df.duplicated`. The remedy is to choose a different name for my new column or to call it using explicit indexing `df['duplicated']`.